# Use virtualAttributes with jsonSchema in objection

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, objection.js

I would like to have an additional column with a modified value from another column:
Now I have next code like this but it doesn't work:

```
const { Model } = require("objection");  
    class TestModel extends Model {
      static get tableName() {
        return "testTable";
      }
    
    
      static get virtualAttributes() {
        return ["someNewField"];
      }
    
      someNewField() {
        return this.someField+'testString';
      }
    
      static get jsonSchema() {
        return {
          type: "object",
          properties: {
            someField:{ type: "string" },
          },
        };
      }
    }
    
    module.exports = {
      TestModel,
    };
```

I got error like

```
"message": "Cannot query field \"someNewField\" on type \"testTable\".",
```

My grapql query:

```
{TestModels{
  someNewField,
}
```

Comment: please add also the query that throws the error

Comment: @MikaelLepistö I added this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual attributes are created in javascript side after data has been fetched from the database. So there is no such column named `someNewField` generated to DB.

So now you are trying to create a query that tries to find data from DB that is not there at all.

There is no generic workaround how to make this work. If you can explain your use-case what you are trying to achieve here, I might be able to suggest something to do in that specific case.

Comment: I use objection and objection-graphql. I'm looking for a way that will allow modifying the date that will get the client using graphql queries, I dont understang how change it on the server side. For example I get value like 100, I would like to change it in $100

Comment: I don't know if graphql + objection supports that.